# Why is drupal_json only returning page HTML?

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Why is `drupal_json` only returning page HTML?

Here's the code:

**PHP:**

```
//Add js
function update_ajax_init(){
   drupal_add_js("....");
}

//Function hook menu of me
function update_ajax_menu(){
$items = array();

  $items['ajax/refresh'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,  
    'page callback' => 'ajax_update_node',
    'title' => 'Ajax update'
  );
}

//Function main process return data json
function ajax_update_node(){
   return drupal_json(array("flag"=>true));
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.update_node").click(function(){
        var params = {node_id: $(this).atrr("rel")};
        $.ajax(
           type: "POST",
           url:  "ajax/refresh",
           data:  params,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(response){
               if (response.flag == true){
                   alert("Success");
               }
           }
        );
    });
});
```

Why is the response value all HTML code and not json? `{'flag'=>true}`

Response from filefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
..................
..................
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks very similar to [How can I return actual JSON using Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14689/how-can-i-return-actual-json-using-drupal)

It looks like you're going to use it for some auto-complete function. Either way you're function `ajax_update_node` should be something like this. I would also rename the function as it looks like you're implementing a hook. It's very similar to `hook_nodeapi`.

```
function ajax_update_node() {
    $result = array('flag' => true);
    drupal_json($result);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7 and setup a "delivery callback" in your hook_menu declaration to call it.